# Sorting items filtered by tag

Tags: mysql, join, tags, query-optimization, sql-order-by

I want to implement a very common feature - filtering some items by tag. There are many tutorials on the internet with examples of how to do it. The query is quite simple and fast (assuming proper indexes exist).
But usually the filtered items need to be sorted by some field. For example, when you filter questions by tag on SO, you get your results sorted.

To accomplish this task (assuming we need to sort by rating), one could write:

```
SELECT item.id FROM item
    INNER JOIN taggeditem ON taggeditem.item_id = item.id
WHERE
    taggeditem.tag_id = 1234
ORDER BY item.rating DESC
```

We have indexes `(taggeditem.tag_id)`, `(item.id)`, `(item.rating`)
The problem with this query is that mysql can't use index on item.rating, because the key used to fetch the rows is not the same as the one used in the ORDER BY ([MySQL: ORDER BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)). This leads to using a temporary table and filesort, which in turn leads to slow execution time.

The solution I came up with is to denormalize sort field to the `taggeditem` table, so that I could create index `(tag_id, item_rating)` on `taggeditem`.

I've searched for similar questions at SO, and found only this one: [Mysql slow query: INNER JOIN + ORDER BY causes filesort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015391). The solution was the same.

So, I want to ask, is this a common solution to this problem? Is it a good practice to denormalize a bunch of sort fields to taggeditem, such as created, rating? At SO you can sort using 4 different parameters (newest, hot, votes, active) - does it mean that they denormalized fields which are used to sort results?
Are there any alternatives to this solution?

Comment: is items or item ? confuse ... you might want to re-check the SQL

Comment: I edited the SQL, I meant table item of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard alternative - change server system variables.
For example, you can experiment with sort_buffer_size value (default 2MB).
[More](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) about it.

Comment: The problem is not only in filesort, but in creating a temporary table. Most of the time it spends copying to temporary table. Can I do anything with that?

Comment: Sorry but no. It's MySQL limitation.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you're using a JOIN, and filter out on the joined table, you're stuck with bad performance.

As you said, the only way to avoid this is to create a denormalized table.

For SO's sorts, I think they have no such issue: they just have to sort answers by a column of the answers' table (something like `SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id = 1234 SORT BY answer_date`, with an index on `question_id, answer_date`)

I'm also looking for such solutions, with multi-valued columns, and that's really difficult (denormalized data would be huge, as it needs to cross all values in the multi-valued columns)

Comment: SO have such issue: when you filter by tag, you see newest questions first (or hottest, it doesn't matter).