# MySQL indexes - what are the best practices according to this table and queries

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

i have this table (500,000 row)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listings` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `hash` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `source_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `short_link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` mediumint(5) NOT NULL,
  `title` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `description` mediumtext,
  `content` mediumtext,
  `images` mediumtext,
  `videos` mediumtext,
  `views` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `comments` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `comments_update` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `editor_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `auther_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdby_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `createdon` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `editedby_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `editedon` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `deletedon` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `deletedby_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `deletedfor` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `publishedon` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `publishedby_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `hash` (`hash`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

i'm thinking to make each query by the `publishedon between x and y` (show in all the site just records of 1 month)

in the same time, i want to add with the `publishedon` in the where clause `published, cat_id , source_id`

some thing like this:

```
SELECT * FROM listings 
WHERE (publishedon BETWEEN 1441105258 AND 1443614458) 
  AND (published = 1) 
  AND (cat_id in(1,2,3,4,5)) 
  AND (source_id  in(1,2,3,4,5))
```

that query is ok and fast until now without indexing, but when trying to use `order by publishedon` its became too slow, so i used this index

```
CREATE INDEX `listings_pcs` ON listings(
    `publishedon` DESC,
    `published` ,
    `cat_id` ,
    `source_id`
)
```

it worked and the `order by publishedon` became fast, now i want to `order by views` like this

```
SELECT * FROM listings 
WHERE (publishedon BETWEEN 1441105258 AND 1443614458) 
  AND (published = 1) 
  AND (cat_id in(1,2,3,4,5)) 
  AND (source_id  in(1,2,3,4,5)) 
ORDER BY views DESC
```

this is the explanation 
[image]
this query is too slow because of `ORDER BY views DESC`

then i'm tried to drop the old index and add this

```
CREATE INDEX `listings_pcs` ON listings(
    `publishedon` DESC,
    `published` ,
    `cat_id` ,
    `source_id`,
    `views` DESC
)
```

its too slow also

what about if i use just single index on `publishedon`?
what about using single index on cat_id,source_id,views,publishedon?

i can change the query dependencies like publishedon in one month if i found other indexing method depend on any other columns

what about making index in (`cat_id`, `source_id`, `publishedon`, `published`) ? but in some cases i will use source_id only?

what is the best indexing schema for that table

Comment: I removed the sql-server tag because the syntax is clearly MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One important general note as to why your query isn't getting any faster despite your attempts is that `DESC` on indexes is not currently supported on MySQL. See this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10130260/1935338), and [the source](https://wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL) from which it comes.

In this case, your largest problem is in the sheer size of your record. If the engine decides it wouldn't really be faster to use an index, then it won't.

You have a few options, and all are actually pretty decent and can probably help you see significant improvement.

#### A note on SQL

First, I want to make a quick note about indexing in SQL. While I don't think it's the solution for your woes, it was your main question, and can help.

It usually helps me to think about indexing in three different buckets. The ***absolutely***, the **maybe**, and the *never*. You certainly don't have anything in your indexing that's in the *never* column, but there are some I would consider "**maybe**" indexes.

***absolutely***: This is your primary key and any foreign keys. It is also any key you will reference on a very regular basis to pull a small set of data from the massive data you have.

**maybe**: These are columns which, while you may reference them regularly, are not really referenced by themselves. In fact, through analysis and using `EXPLAIN` as [@Machavity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32923120/1935338) recommends in his answer, you may find that by the time these columns are used to strip out fields, there aren't that many fields anyway. An example of a column that would solidly be in this pile for me would be the `published` column. Keep in mind that every `INDEX` adds to the work your queries need to do.

*Also:* Composite keys are a good choice when you're regularly searching for data based on two different columns. More on that later.

#### Options, options, options...

There are a number of options to consider, and each one has some drawbacks. Ultimately I would consider each of these on a case-by-case basis as I don't see any of these to be a silver bullet. Ideally, you'd test a few different solutions against your current setting and see which one runs the fastest using a nice scientific test.

1. **Split your SQL table into two or more separate tables.**

This is one of the few times where, despite the number of columns in your table, I wouldn't rush to try to split your table into smaller chunks. If you decided to split it into smaller chunks, however, I'd argue that your `[action]edon`, `[action]edby_id`, and `[action]ed` could easily be put into another table, `actions`:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| action_id | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| action    | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| date      | datetime    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| user_id   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

The downside to this is that it does not allow you to ensure there is only one creation date without a `TRIGGER`. The upside is that when you don't have to sort as many columns with as many indexes when you're sorting by date. Also, it allows you to sort not only be `created`, but also by all of your other actions.

*Edit: As requested, here is a sample sorting query*

```
SELECT * FROM listings 
INNER JOIN actions ON actions.listing_id = listings.id
WHERE (actions.action = 'published') 
  AND (listings.published = 1) 
  AND (listings.cat_id in(1,2,3,4,5)) 
  AND (listings.source_id  in(1,2,3,4,5)) 
  AND (actions.actiondate between 1441105258 AND 1443614458)
ORDER BY listings.views DESC
```

*Theoretically, it should cut down on the number of rows you're sorting against because it's only pulling relevant data. I don't have a dataset like yours so I can't test it right now!*

If you put a composite key on `actiondate` and `listings.id`, this should help to increase speed.

As I said, I don't think this is the best solution for you right now because I'm not convinced it's going to give you the maximum optimization. This leads me to my next suggestion:

2. **Create a month field**

I used [this nifty tool](http://www.timestampconvert.com/?go2=true&offset=4&timestamp=1443614458&Submit=%20%20%20%20%20%20Convert%20to%20Date%20%20%20%20%20%20) to confirm what I thought I understood of your question: You are sorting by month here. Your example is specifically looking between September 1st and September 30th, inclusive.

So another option is for you to split your integer function into a `month`, `day`, and `year` field. You can still have your timestamp, but timestamps aren't all that great for searching. Run an `EXPLAIN` on even a simple query and you'll see for yourself.

That way, you can just index the month and year fields and do a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM listings 
WHERE (publishedmonth = 9)
  AND (publishedyear = 2015) 
  AND (published = 1) 
  AND (cat_id in(1,2,3,4,5)) 
  AND (source_id  in(1,2,3,4,5)) 
ORDER BY views DESC
```

Slap an `EXPLAIN` in front and you should see massive improvements.

Because you're planning on referring to a month and a day, you may want to add a composite key against month and year, rather than a key on both separately, for added gains.

***Note**: I want to be clear, this is not the "correct" way to do things. It is convenient, but denormalized. If you want the correct way to do things, you'd adapt something like [this link](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/01/overlapping-ranges-mysql/) but I think that would require you to seriously reconsider your table, and I haven't tried anything like this, having lacked the need, and, frankly, will, to brush up on my geometry. I think it's a little overkill for what you're trying to do.*

3. **Do your heavy sorting elsewhere**

This was hard for me to come to terms with because I like to do things the "SQL" way wherever possible, but that is not always the best solution. Heavy computing, for example, is best done using your programming language, leaving SQL to handle relationships.

The former CTO of Digg sorted using PHP instead of MySQL and received a [4,000% performance increase](http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/3/23/digg-4000-performance-increase-by-sorting-in-php-rather-than.html). You're probably not scaling out to this level, of course, so the performance trade-offs won't be clearcut unless you test it out yourself. Still, the concept is sound: the database is the bottleneck, and computer memory is dirt cheap by comparison.

There are doubtless a lot more tweaks that can be done. Each of these has a drawback and requires some investment. The best answer is to test two or more of these and see which one helps you get the most improvement.

Comment: you deserve my all reputation not just 200, this is the most useful answer i see until now,but i can not make any thing yet, the idea of "Overlapping ranges: MySQL" is great but i can not make it in my table because i can not understand the relationship used in it, i made a new column "`lrange` linestring NOT NULL" and made update on all colmun like this "UPDATE `mubashier_listings` SET `lrange` = LineString(Point(-1, `publishedon`))" then i tested this query "SELECT * FROM `mubashier_listings` WHERE MBRContains(lrange, Point(0, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-09-31'))" its return 0

Comment: and how can i sort by date using the "action" table

Comment: the action table doesn't contains views column and your query using "ORDER BY actions.views DESC" ,and i can not understand thw whole idea, how this will reduce the number of rows, each listing will have more than one row in this action table, this mean in listing may be 100 listing and action table will be 300

Comment: Fixed the query. The reason it should reduce the number of rows is because your current structure has so many records being queried that it has to go through every single record. In a joined table, it will only pull records which  fit the parameters listed, which means you're sorting against a subset of records that should be considerably smaller than the total number of records you have. I am in no way certain about this and think sorting using PHP is your best bet. Still, if you have time to test it it may be a good improvement. If you did I'd be interested to know how it worked.

Comment: DESC is a red herring.  Change it to ASC, and the query still won't work faster.  The problem is with the INs and range.  They prevent the use of the index for ORDER BY.

Comment: in action example,which fields in which table should i index it

Comment: You should index any column you reference regularly. In this case that is probably all of them. In reality you would probably be indexing three times as many columns if they were in the original table. To put it another way, if you don't anticipate regularly querying against something using `WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, etc., then don't make it an index.

Comment: Rick James... It is not the `IN` or range independently. MySQL is very good at translating those, although I'd probably sooner do a range than an `IN`. The reason it's slow is because there are too many options being queried and MySQL doesn't read the index at all. You are right about the DESC/ASC being a red herring in this case. I sort of forgot I started the post that way after I started running tests, but index DESC is never going to work in MySQL current versions.

Comment: take a look at this : http://i.imgur.com/9yiaDUd.png (very slow,using tmp and filesort) the indexing on action "composed" (action,created_month,created_year,created_day) and on listings (cat_id,source_id) and this is the query used "EXPLAIN SELECT listings.id,listings.title FROM listings listings INNER JOIN listing_actions actions ON actions.listing_id = listings.id WHERE actions.action = 'published' and actions.created_month = 6 and actions.created_year = 2015 order by listings.views desc LIMIT 10 "

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015391/mysql-slow-query-inner-join-order-by-causes-filesort might help you.

Comment: That question/answer, translated to your issue, assumes that you should be making a composite key against listing_id, and your time column(s). I'm thinking that the month,day,year solution is not really necessary when you're using a separate table but I am not sure. Worth trying both ways I suppose!

Answer (score 13):

This query:

```
SELECT *
FROM listings
WHERE (publishedon BETWEEN 1441105258 AND 1443614458) AND
      (published = 1) AND
      (cat_id in (1,2,3,4,5)) AND
      (source_id in (1,2,3,4,5));
```

Is hard to optimize with only indexes.  The best index is one that starts with `published` and then has the other columns -- it is not clear what their order should be.  The reason is because all but `published` are not using `=`.

Because your performance problem is on a sort, that suggests that lots of rows are being returned.  Typically, an index is used to satisfy the `WHERE` clause before the index can be used for the `ORDER BY`.  That makes this hard to optimize.

Suggestions . . . None are that great:

- If you are going to access the data by month, then you might consider partitioning the data by month.  That will make the query without the `ORDER BY` faster, but won't help the `ORDER BY`.
- Try various orders of columns after `published` in the index.  You might find the most selective column(s).  But, once again, this speeds the query before the sorting.
- Think about ways that you can structure the query to have more equality conditions in the `WHERE` clause or to return a smaller set of data.
- (Not really recommended) Put an index on `published` and the ordering column.  Then use a subquery to fetch the data.  Put the inequality conditions (`IN` and so on) in the outer query.  The subquery will use the index for sorting and then filter the results.

The reason the last is not recommended is because SQL (and MySQL) do not guarantee the ordering of results from a subquery.  However, because MySQL materializes subqueries, the results really are in order.  I don't like using undocumented side effects, which can change from version to version.

Comment: how can i make the partitioning, i'm using unixtime, can you give me the sytax to make this ... and how can i make new partitions for the new rows in the feature

Comment: and this is mean there is no any way to use publishedon BETWEEN  and sorting by views, what is the best way to sort by views without publishedon

Comment: Year can learn about partitions here:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html.  If you were selecting an entire partition and had the right index on another column, then you might be able to convince MySQL to avoid the `order by`.  But that is not exactly your query.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I'd at least `INDEX` the fields in question individually. You're building multi-column indices but it's clear you're pulling a lot of disparate records as well. Having the columns indexed individually can't hurt.

Something you should do is use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) which lets you look under the hood of how MySQL is pulling the data. It could further point to what is slowing your query down.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM listings 
WHERE (publishedon BETWEEN 1441105258 AND 1443614458) 
  AND (published = 1) 
  AND (cat_id in(1,2,3,4,5)) 
  AND (source_id  in(1,2,3,4,5)) 
ORDER BY views DESC
```

Comment: . . To a close approximation, MySQL only uses one index per query.  Having multiple indexes generally does *not* help.  Composite indexes are usually more appropriate for more complex statements.  (Multiple indexes address the issue of optimization for multiple queries or queries that have subqueries.)

Comment: @UnixMan Yeah, `filesort` is your enemy. `MySQL must do an extra pass to find out how to retrieve the rows in sorted order. The sort is done by going through all rows according to the join type and storing the sort key and pointer to the row for all rows that match the WHERE clause.`

Comment: @UnixMan The best solution I know is either a better index than what you have or what Gordon suggested

Comment: how i can index the views coulmn

Comment: @GordonLinoff There is a slight change in what you said. MySQL only uses one index per the table mentioned in a query.

Answer (score 1):

The rows of your table are enormous (all those `mediumtext` columns), so sorting `SELECT *` is going to have a lot of overhead.  That's a simple reality of your schema design.  `SELECT *` is generally considered harmful to performance. If you can enumerate the columns you need, and you can leave out some of the big ones, you'll get better performance.

You showed us a query with the following filter criteria

1. single-value equality on `published`.
2. range matching on `publishedon`.
3. set matching on `cat_id`
4. set matching on `source_id`.
5. Ordering on views.

Due to the way MySQL indexing works on MyISAM, the following compound covering index will probably serve you well. It's hard to be sure unless you try it.

```
CREATE INDEX listings_x_pub_date_cover ON listings( 
     published, publishedon, cat_id, source_id, views, id )
```

To satisfy your query the MySQL engine will random-access the index at the appropriate value of `published`, and then at the begiining of the `publishedon` range. It will then scan through the index filtering on the other two filtering criteria. Finally, it sorts and and uses the `id` value to look up each row that passes the filter. Give it a try.

If that performance isn't good enough try this so-called `deferred join` operation.

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM listings a
  JOIN ( SELECT id, views
           FROM listings
          WHERE published = 1
            AND publishedon BETWEEN 1441105258
                                AND 1443614458
            AND cat_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
            AND source_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
          ORDER BY views DESC
       ) b ON a.id = b.id
 ORDER BY b.views DESC
```

This does the heavy lifting of ordering with just the id and views columns without having to shuffle all those massive text columns. It may or may not help, because the ordering has to be repeated in the outer query. This kind of thing DEFINITELY helps when you have `ORDER BY ... LIMIT n` pattern in your query, but you don't.

Finally, considering the size of these rows, you may get best performance by doing this inner query from your php program:

```
         SELECT id
           FROM listings
          WHERE published = 1
            AND publishedon BETWEEN 1441105258
                                AND 1443614458
            AND cat_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
            AND source_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
          ORDER BY views DESC
```

and then fetching the full rows of the table one-by-one using these `id` values in an inner loop. (This query that fetches just id values should be quite fast with the help of the index I mentioned.)  The inner loop solution would be ugly, but if your text columns are really big (each `mediumtext` column can hold up to 16MiB) it's probably your best bet.

tl;dr.  Create the index mentioned. Get rid of `SELECT *` if you possibly can, giving a list of columns you need instead. Try the deferred join query.  If it's still not good enough try the nested query.

Comment: my problem is to sorting by views not by publishedon

Comment: True, I missed that. Most of my suggestions are still relevant. Please see my edit.

Comment: I disagree.  (1) single-valued; (2) set-valued, (3) range.  And nothing after the first range will be used.  Exception: a covering index.