# MYSQL - order by indexed column

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this table with 500,000 row

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listings` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `source_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` mediumint(5) NOT NULL,
  `title` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `views_point` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `publishedon_hourly` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `views_point` (`views_point`),
  KEY `listings` (`publishedon_hourly`,`published`,`cat_id`,`source_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED AUTO_INCREMENT=365513 ;
```

i want to make a query like this

```
SELECT *
FROM listings
WHERE (
`publishedon_hourly`
BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-09-5 12:00:00' )AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-10-5 12:00:00' ) ) AND ( published =1 ) AND cat_id
IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )
ORDER BY views_point DESC
LIMIT 10
```

this query some time work as i want exactly ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952051/mysql-indexing-and-using-filesort/32952266)) , but after some opinions, this is incorrect, i searched on the web for solution, i found

this : http://venublog.com/2007/11/29/mysql-how-to-avoid-filesort/
and this: http://www.getsymphony.com/discuss/issues/view/657/
and i add index on `views_point` then tried this query

```
select t1.* 
from  listings t1 
left outer join  listings t2 on (t1.views_point=t2.views_point) 
order by t1.views_point 
limit 10
```

and this the explain

[image]

but i can not add this condition

```
`publishedon_hourly` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-09-5 12:00:00' ) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-09-5 12:00:00' ) ) AND ( published =1 ) AND cat_id = 5
```

i don't know, which one should i assign to (t1 or t2) ?

in the other hand what about this way

```
SELECT *
FROM listings
WHERE (
`publishedon_hourly` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-09-5 00:00:00' ) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-09-5 23:00:00' ))
AND (published =1)
and views_point is not null
ORDER BY views_point DESC limit 20
```

if any one will not be good,can any one tell me please how the big blogs get the posts by hits?

Comment: Why on Earth you want to self join the table?

Comment: simplify your OP, remove unused or not important columns from `CREATE TABLE` for OP, delete all data except 5 records with simple content. Explain not what you were trying during other experiments, but just what is your expected result sholud be according to those 5 sample records.

Comment: We don't know which one you should add it to unless you explain what result you're trying to get.

Comment: Also, why would you use a `LEFT JOIN` when joining to the same table? There can't be any non-matching rows, so you should use a more efficient `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @Victor because of this http://venublog.com/2007/11/29/mysql-how-to-avoid-filesort/

Comment: @Alex this is just sample, the table which i test on it has 500000 row

Comment: Did I ask for that number? I just gave you suggestion how to help us to resolve the problem you have.

Comment: I will give you any thing you want, please help me

Comment: Read my first comment and edit your post according what I've asked

Comment: what do you mean by OP

Answer (score 1):

You should split your `listings` index to separate indices.

Apart from this, given that you sort by `t1`, it is almost certain that you should specify `t1` for all conditions.

EDIT:
Use condition as

```
`t1`.`publishedon_hourly` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-09-5 12:00:00' ) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-09-5 12:00:00' ) ) AND ( `t1`.`published` = 1 ) AND `t1`.`cat_id` = 5
```

Comment: thank you for your help, this problem made me crazy, i can not solve it sence 6 days, could you please give me some sql codes to test it, i have no big knowledge in sql, please help me