# Slow inner join order query

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-order-by, inner-join

I have a problem with the speed of query. Question is similar to this one, but can't find solution. Explain says that MySQL is using: `Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort` on companies table.

[Mysql slow query: INNER JOIN + ORDER BY causes filesort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015391/mysql-slow-query-inner-join-order-by-causes-filesort)

Slow query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM companies 
    INNER JOIN post_indices
        ON companies.post_index_id = post_indices.id
    WHERE companies.deleted_at is NULL
    ORDER BY post_indices.id
    LIMIT 1;
# 1 row in set (5.62 sec)
```

But if I remove where statement from query it is really fast:

```sql
SELECT * FROM companies
    INNER JOIN post_indices
        ON companies.post_index_id = post_indices.id
    ORDER BY post_indices.id
    LIMIT 1;
# 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've tried using different indexes on `companies` table:

1. `index_companies_on_deleted_at`
2. `index_companeis_on_post_index_id`
3. `index_companies_on_deleted_at_and_post_index_id`
4. `index_companies_on_post_index_id_and_deleted_at`

`index_companies_on_deleted_at` index is automatically selected by MySQL. Stats for same query using above indexes:

1. 5.6 sec
2. 3.4 sec
3. 8.5 sec
4. 3.5 sec

Any ideas how to improve my query speed? Again said - without `where deleted_at is null` condition query is instant..

- Companies table has 1.3 mil of rows.
- PostIndices table has 3k rows.

**UPDATE 1:**

Order by `post_indices.id` is used for simplicity since it's indexed already. But it will be used on other columns of join table (`post_indices`). So sort on `companies.post_index_id` wont solve this issue

**UPDATE 2:** for Rick James

Your query takes only 0.04 sec to accomplish. And explain says that `index_companies_on_deleted_at_and_post_index_id` index is used. So yes, it works better, but this doesn't solve my problem (need to order on post_indices columns, will do this in future, so id `post_indices.id` used for simplicity of example. In future it will be for example `post_indices.city`).

My query with WHERE, but without ORDER BY is instant.

**UPDATE 3:**

EXPLAIN query. Also I noticed that order of indexes matters. `index_companies_on_deleted_at` index is used if it's higher (created earlier) then `index_companies_on_deleted_at_and_post_index_id`. Otherwise later index is used. I mean automatically selected by MySQL.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM companies INNER JOIN post_indices ON post_indices.id = companies.post_index_id WHERE companies.deleted_at IS NULL ORDER BY post_indices.id LIMIT 1;
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                  | key                           | key_len | ref                                                  | rows   | filtered | Extra                                                               |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | companies    | NULL       | ref    | index_companies_on_post_index_id,index_companies_on_deleted_at,index_companies_on_deleted_at_and_post_index_id | index_companies_on_deleted_at | 6       | const                                                | 638692 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | post_indices | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                        | PRIMARY                       | 4       | enbro_purecrm_eu_development.companies.post_index_id |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                                                                |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)


mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM companies USE INDEX(index_companies_on_post_index_id) INNER JOIN post_indices ON post_indices.id = companies.post_index_id WHERE companies.deleted_at IS NULL ORDER BY post_indices.id LIMIT 1;
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | partitions | type   | possible_keys                    | key     | key_len | ref                                                  | rows    | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | companies    | NULL       | ALL    | index_companies_on_post_index_id | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                                 | 1277385 |    10.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | post_indices | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                          | PRIMARY | 4       | enbro_purecrm_eu_development.companies.post_index_id |       1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)


mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM companies USE INDEX(index_companies_on_deleted_at_and_post_index_id) INNER JOIN post_indices ON post_indices.id = companies.post_index_id WHERE companies.deleted_at IS NULL ORDER BY post_indices.id LIMIT 1;
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                   | key                                             | key_len | ref                                                  | rows   | filtered | Extra                                                  |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | companies    | NULL       | ref    | index_companies_on_deleted_at_and_post_index_id | index_companies_on_deleted_at_and_post_index_id | 6       | const                                                | 638692 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | post_indices | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                         | PRIMARY                                         | 4       | enbro_purecrm_eu_development.companies.post_index_id |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                                                   |
+----+-------------+--------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE 4:**

I've removed non related columns:

```
| companies | CREATE TABLE `companies` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`post_index_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`vat` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`note` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`state` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new',
`deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`lead_list_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `index_companies_on_vat` (`vat`),
KEY `index_companies_on_post_index_id` (`post_index_id`),
KEY `index_companies_on_state` (`state`),
KEY `index_companies_on_deleted_at` (`deleted_at`),
KEY `index_companies_on_deleted_at_and_post_index_id` (`deleted_at`,`post_index_id`),
KEY `index_companies_on_lead_list_id` (`lead_list_id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_5fc7f5c6b9` FOREIGN KEY (`lead_list_id`) REFERENCES `lead_lists` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_79719355c6` FOREIGN KEY (`post_index_id`) REFERENCES `post_indices` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2523518 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |

| post_indices | CREATE TABLE `post_indices` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`county` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`postal_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`group_part` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`group_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`group_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3101 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

**UPDATE 5:**

Another developer tested same query on his local machine with exactly same data set (dump/restore). And he got totally different explain:

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM companies      INNER JOIN post_indices         ON companies.post_index_id = post_indices.id     WHERE companies.deleted_at is NULL     ORDER BY post_indices.id     LIMIT 1;
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys                                                                                                  | key                                             | key_len | ref                                                | rows | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | post_indices | index | PRIMARY                                                                                                        | PRIMARY                                         | 4       | NULL                                               |    1 | NULL                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | companies    | ref   | index_companies_on_post_index_id,index_companies_on_deleted_at,index_companies_on_deleted_at_and_post_index_id | index_companies_on_deleted_at_and_post_index_id | 11      | const,enbro_purecrm_eu_development.post_indices.id |  283 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Same query on his PC is instant. Have no idea why it is happening.. I've also tried to use `STRAIGHT_JOIN`. When I force `post_indices` table to be read first by MySQL, it is blazing fast too. But still it is mistery for me, why same query on another machine is fast (mysql -v 5.6.27) and slow on my machine (mysql -v 5.7.10)

So it seems that problem is MySQL using wrong table as first table to read.

Comment: Try to put the where deleted_at is null inside the ON clause ->> use AND deleted_at is null

Comment: If you mean this query `select companies.* from companies inner join post_indices on companies.post_index_id = post_indices.id AND COMPANIES.DELETED_AT IS NULL order by post_indices.id limit 1;` then result is same unfortunately

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT...` for each.

Comment: Check Update 3 for EXPLAIN query please

Answer (score 2):

Does this work better?

```
SELECT * FROM companies AS c
INNER JOIN post_indices AS pi
    ON c.post_index_id = pi.id
WHERE    c.deleted_at is NULL
ORDER BY c.post_index_id           -- Note
LIMIT 1;

INDEX(deleted_at, post_index_id)  -- note
```

For that matter, how fast does it run *with* the `WHERE`, but *without* the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: I agree on this.  via transitive, they should have ordered by the COMPANIES post_index_id instead of the pi.id since it was part of the same index...

Comment: Check Update 2 please for details on running these queries.

Comment: Is it actually possible to do what I'm trying to do in SQL with good speed (less then 500-1000ms)? PostIndices table is only 3k rows atm, and it will grow. So this query time will also grow a lot (with 1k post_indices query is almost instant). Maybe I'm just using wrong tool? PS I've also tried to use same query in PostgreSQL (with exactly same data), and it is done there in 1.0-1.2s.

Comment: "used for simplicity of example" -- I hope you realize now that that simplification can make a big difference.  `ORDER BY city LIMIT 1` does not make much sense, either.

Comment: well, query that will be used could look similar to this one: `SELECT * FROM companies AS c INNER JOIN post_indices as pi ON c.post_index_id = p.id WHERE c.deleted_at is NULL ORDER BY ci.city LIMIT 25;`. But if I can't get decent speed when trying ORDER BY on primary key, I think I wont be able to do same on any other column (even indexed) too. Maybe you can suggest what approach should be used for this? The goal is to sort `companies` by `post_indices` column in the table.

Comment: For _that_ query, add `INDEX(city)` and see what the `EXPLAIN` is like.  The Optimizer _may_ choose to start with that table in hopes of avoiding the 'filesort'.  Note that you have 4 aliases for 2 tables.  Please add `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables to the question.

Comment: I've tried adding this index, but it was also slow. Afterwards I've started experimenting with `post_indices.id` column. Check Update 4 please

Comment: If there are 800 non-deleted companies per post_code and you `order by city limit 25`, won't you only get companies in Ab Ketleby, Ab Lench, Abberley, and maybe a few more towns?  If you are going to have `OFFSET`, that makes a big difference.  Etc.

Comment: you are right. It is used in table, so LIMIT and OFFSET are used for pagination. Check Update 5 please

Comment: If it boils down to "fast on 5.6 and slow on 5.7", please file a bug report on http://bugs.mysql.com ; the developers love (hate) to hear about regressions.

Comment: [Why OFFSET is a bad way to do pagination](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).

Comment: Okay. Will downgrade on my machine to check this first. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Using the following optimizer hints, should force MySQL to use the plan that your colleague observed:

```
SELECT * FROM post_indices 
    STRAIGHT_JOIN companies FORCE INDEX(index_companies_on_deleted_at_and_post_index_id)
        ON companies.post_index_id = post_indices.id
    WHERE companies.deleted_at is NULL
    ORDER BY post_indices.id
    LIMIT 1;
```

If you will be sorting on other columns of post_indices, you will need an index on those columns to make this plan work well.

Note that what is the most optimal plan will depend on how frequent deleted_at is NULL.  If deleted_at is frequently NULL, the above plan will be fast. If not, with the above plan one will have to run through many rows of post_indices before a match is found.  Note also that for queries with OFFSET, the same plan may not be the most effective.

I think the issue here is that MySQL decides the join order without considering the effects of ORDER BY and LIMIT.  In other words, it will choose the join order that it thinks is fastest to execute the full join.
Since there is a restriction on the companies table (deleted_at is NULL), I am not surprised that it will start with this table.